# Change image dimension while sending a Generic template message using Facebook graph api

Tags: node.js, image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chatbot

I am trying to build a Facebook chatbot that sometimes sends image as response to user queries. These images are from the response of API requests from my node server and don't sit at my server end.
I am using [Graph api](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages) to send messages automatically from the chatbot whenever a postback is received. 
I am able to get image response back, but the images are not responsive. I have attached a picture for reference.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o05WL.png)
From the Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads/), I don't see any parameter that dynamically changes the image size. As the images I receive are from an external api and not from my server, is there a way around to change the image size and display the image with new dimensions in my chatbot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no image size exactly, but you can set the aspect ratio of the image, which will crop it to that ratio in the template. `payload.image_aspect_ratio` and the options are `horizontal` (1.91:1) or `square` (1:1).

You could also fetch the image with a third party API like Cloudinary, which will do image transforms on the fly.

Comment: Thanks! That actually worked. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/generic#fields mentions the same. But, my images are being cropped for both the options(horizontal & square). Do you have any reference on how to use Cloudinary to manipulate dimensions of an image using an image url?

Comment: @PavanUlichi https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations